# docker run command failed with error Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401)

Tags: docker, openstack, devstack

I am not able to figure out which authentication is required to run container
Any help will be highly appreciated

I have setup devstack on Ubuntu o.s and then trying to run below container using command

```
sudo docker run --name kuryr-libnetwork \
  --net=host \
  --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
  -e SERVICE_USER=admin \
  -e SERVICE_PROJECT_NAME=admin \
  -e SERVICE_PASSWORD=admin \
  -e SERVICE_DOMAIN_NAME=Default \
  -e USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default \
  -e IDENTITY_URL=http://192.168.105.102/identity/v3 \
  -v /var/log/kuryr:/var/log/kuryr \
  -v /var/run/openvswitch:/var/run/openvswitch \
  kuryr/libnetwork
```

**But failed with error logs as :**

```
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 CRITICAL kuryr [-] Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-fee37d27-9851-4d88-955f-239588ffce7a)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kuryr_libnetwork/server.py", line 43, in <module>
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     configure_app()
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kuryr_libnetwork/server.py", line 27, in configure_app
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     controllers.check_for_neutron_ext_support()
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kuryr_libnetwork/controllers.py", line 89, in check_for_neutron_ext_support
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     app.neutron.show_extension(MANDATORY_NEUTRON_EXTENSION)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 736, in show_extension
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     return self.get(self.extension_path % ext_alias, params=_params)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 360, in get
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     headers=headers, params=params)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 337, in retry_request
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     headers=headers, params=params)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 288, in do_request
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     resp, replybody = self.httpclient.do_request(action, method, body=body)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 310, in do_request
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     self._check_uri_length(url)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 303, in _check_uri_length
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     uri_len = len(self.endpoint_url) + len(url)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 317, in endpoint_url
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     return self.get_endpoint()
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 158, in get_endpoint
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     return self.session.get_endpoint(auth or self.auth, **kwargs)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 808, in get_endpoint
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     return auth.get_endpoint(self, **kwargs)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 212, in get_endpoint
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     service_catalog = self.get_access(session).service_catalog
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 136, in get_access
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     self.auth_ref = self.get_auth_ref(session)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/generic/base.py", line 194, in get_auth_ref
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     return self._plugin.get_auth_ref(session, **kwargs)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/base.py", line 167, in get_auth_ref
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     authenticated=False, log=False, **rkwargs)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 718, in post
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     return self.request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 607, in request
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr     raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-fee37d27-9851-4d88-955f-239588ffce7a)
2019-05-17 09:57:27.369 8 ERROR kuryr
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```